# Android: why are CardView margins not showing white background?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have set up a CardView in a RecyclerView list.  The layout_marginTop and layout_marginBottom are showing a grey color rather than the white background I had hoped to see (image below).  Any ideas on how to get the top and bottom margins to show a white background?

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"  />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the TextView background and added this background to the CardView:
"card_view:cardBackgroundColor="some color""

Answer (score 0):

```
Add some margin to card 

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're actually populating it with data from your domain model, i.e. check that you've implemented `<data>` and `<variable>` tags and that you've set your `android:text="@{}"` to the appropriate object.